# how to normalize a dataframe to utf-8 in Python? Getting "'charmap' codec can't encode characters" error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, unicode, utf-8

There are other discussion around this but I'm not seeing how to handle errors from a dataframe that contains non-UTF-8 characters.

I have a dataframe (imported from pdf) that gives me this error when I try to print to a log file:

```
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 154-155: character maps to <undefined>
```

But most posts I see are how to deal with strings. Like these...the second one mentions dataframes but there's no clear solution there.

[Pandas UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307384/pandas-unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character)

[several � characters in a dataframe pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400410/several-characters-in-a-dataframe-pandas)

They give this solution but it takes a string as an input, not a dataframe.

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFD', 'some string').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

So, how can I do a similar operation for the whole dataframe?

Comment: A better fix is probably to normalize *before* you read this data into a dataframe.

Comment: We can’t tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual contents of the data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors